# fetching number from addressbook issue

Tags: ios, addressbook

i am using following code for this purpose

```
 ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSString* mobile=@"";
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            //NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            //NSLog(@"%@", phone);
            mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel]) {
                NSLog(@"mobile:");
            } else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel]) {
                NSLog(@"iphone:");
            } else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhonePagerLabel]) {
                NSLog(@"pager:");
            }
            [mobile release];
            mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSLog(@"%@", mobile);
            [_Phonearray addObject:mobile]; 
        }
```

now my problem is that  nslog of _phonearray is like this

_

```
Phonearray(
    "(658) 932-6593",
    "(654) 498-9878"
)
```

but i want like

```
_Phonearray(
    "6589326593",
    "6544989878"
)
```

so what chances should i do in code:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to remove all non-number characters from `mobile`? I found a method here:

[Removing all non wanted characters using the NSCharacterSet - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676003/1523962)

```
NSCharacterSet* charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet] ;
mobile = [[mobile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""] ;
```